# Spring Data MongoDB: group by a conditional field

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

While building a MongoDB aggregation it is possible to use a [*$ifNull*](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operation within a [*$group stage*](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```
db.getCollection('my-collection').aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: { $ifNull: [ "$nullable_field", "$not_nullable_field" ] }
  }
}])
```

I was not able to translate this into a Spring Data MongoDB aggregation query.

The closer I got solve it was by using a Spring Data *ComputedField*, but the generated aggregation was not built properly in the end, the *$ifNull* array was not closed, which cause the aggregation to return the wrong values.

I'm trying to avoid adding an extra [*$addFields stage*](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to pre-calculate the value desired for the group id.

It is not possible to use the [*Aggregation Repository Methods*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.aggregation) since the query is not static, the matching and sorting values are variable values.

I ended up using only the *$group stage* as a string query, to make it possible to use the *$ifNull* to define the id.

Is there another way to achieve this using Spring Data MongoDB, without adding additional stages as is for a MongoDB query?